# CodeIgniter - Creating default object from empty value

Tags: php, codeigniter, warnings, php-5.4, notice

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Creating default object from empty value

Filename: models/Modeltest.php

Line Number: 13
```

I am trying to create an array in model and returning it to the controller but it is giving this warning ? Can any body help me out how to resolve it ?

My ModelClass Code

```
    $list = Array();
    $list[0]->title = "first blog title";
    $list[0]->author = "author 1";

    $list[1]->title = "second blog title";
    $list[1]->author = "author 2";

    return $list;
```

My Contoller Class Code

```
    $this->load->model("modeltest");
    print_r($this->modeltest->get_articles_list());
```

Comment: `$list = Array();` `$list` is...an array, but you're assigning it object properties

Comment: then shouldn't it be an error ? but this code works and I have just followed some tutorial ? http://codesamplez.com/development/codeigniter-basic-tutorial

Comment: Yes, it's an error, and you posted it right in the question

Comment: @Nisarahmed who wrote that tutorial?It seems he did not tested the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you want something like this:

```
$list = array();
$list[0] = new stdClass;
$list[0]->title = "first blog title";
$list[0]->author = "author 1";
$list[1] = new stdClass;
$list[1]->title = "second blog title";
$list[1]->author = "author 2";
```

But why not using the array as an array?

```
$list = array();
$list[0]['title'] = "first blog title";
$list[0]['author'] = "author 1";
```

Comment: Thankssss alott :) This works ;)

wait 7 mins till i can accept it as answer

Comment: This one is good read if interested [array vs stdClass](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3193765/1564365).