# What is a better way to create new object

Tags: php, object

I have the object `$customer`

I need to create new object `$contact` with the contact information
What is a better way to create it?

```
/** the first way */
$contact = (object) array('name' => $customer->name, 'phone' => $customer->phone, 'email' => $customer->email);

/** the second way */
$contact = new stdClass();
$contact->name = $customer->name;
$contact->phone = $customer->phone;
$contact->email = $customer->email;`
```

Comment: the 2nd way is certainly easier to read.

Comment: 2nd since there is no need for conversion

Comment: How about `$contact = clone $customer;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3193765/when-should-i-use-stdclass-and-when-should-i-use-an-array-in-php-oo-code) for a discussion on using stdClass or an array for holding representative data.

Answer:

1. The first way is very bad, in that you are adding needless overhead in converting an array to an object (when you could use the array for that purpose).
2. The second way works, but is not ideal. It does not truly treat the object (in code) as you would treat an object (in life), and therefore does not fit the object-oriented paradigm. (However, it does seem to be the best option for this situation, as per the comments.)
3. The best way (from an OO perspective) is to define the object class.

Example definition:

```
 class Contact{
   public $name;
   public $phone;
   public $email;

  function __construct($name, $phone, $email) {
    $this->name = $name;
    $this->phone = $phone;
    $this->email = $email;
  }
}
```

Example instantiation:

```
$contact = new Contact($customer->name, 
  $customer->phone,
  $customer->email);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I use the framework where I don't want to define own classes.
Btw. why did you define the function Contact and did not use function __construct?

Comment: @AbraCadaver Says OO design principles.

Comment: @ZdeněkJózsa Are you planning to put methods in the object? Or only data?

Comment: @Kittsil Only data (three values in the code above).

Comment: @ZdeněkJózsa Is there a reason you can't treat the data simply as an array?

Comment: @Kittsil Yes - in the Nette framework I can send only object to the framework frontend template.

Comment: In that case, I'd go with the second option; it is cleaner and should be faster (although I do not usually benchmark `php` code). But I protest that, from a software design perspective, this question feels like asking, "Is it better to smash my toe or my finger with a hammer?"

Comment: @Kittsil Thank you for your discussion.

Comment: @ZdeněkJózsa I forgot the link to the other answer; it has been added. It might be worth supplementing your question with why a) you need to put your data into an object and b) you can't store it in a data array.