# Massive product filter on webpage

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

Currently building a website and I am aiming to create a way for users to filter through thousands of products. I was wondering what the best method is to do so.

Goal:
Database with thousands of products, all with multiple specifications.
Webpage with pagination that shows 15 of those products per page, sorted on rating (one of the specifications) and allows the user to apply all sort of filters and sorting methods.

What is my best approach here?
What do I need in order to build this? Php, AngularJS, etc?

I only know front-end thus far but am expanding my tool set into back-end and would love to be able to build this.

Take care!

Comment: You need a database and PHP(or any server side language). The PHP will receive the filtration and sorting parameters from the client side (via HTML form or Ajax request), connecting to the database and deliver the results back to the client side again.

Comment: Ah great! Then I was on the right track. Do you think this is hard to learn for somebody front-end capabable, or should I be able to do this in a few days?

Comment: Generally speaking If you already wrote any language you can learn a new language fast. Besides what you want can be done by a very small PHP script,  just receive the `http` request parameters, make a SQL query and response to the client with a little HTML snippet or A JSON object. I think you can do it in a couple of days.

Comment: Hey @Accountantم, I have thought myself SQL and basic PHP at this point. Indeed quite easy like you mentioned. I am just trying to work out how to combine the two as well as whether it might be best to use arrays or classes in php to store the data. What are your thoughts on how to pull the SQL data and present it using PHP?

Comment: If you used `mysqli` to interact with a mysql database from PHP then the data will be stored in a result object. loop throw the result and do what you want with the data (e.g build `<tr>` elements or `<option>` elements or build an array of objects and encode it into JSON with `[json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)` function). storing the data in an associative array or class is a matter of personal preference . see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8498114/should-i-use-an-associative-array-or-an-object) on that